# Subnormal series in GL group

Tags: group-theory

What is the longest possible subnormal series in $GL(3,Z_{2^n})$ group. I was managed to find only length 4 subnormal series, which is $\left\{I\right\} \triangleleft  \left\{I,-I\right\}    \triangleleft   SL(3,Z_{2^n})  \triangleleft \left\{ A \in GL(3,Z_{2^n}) \: : \:|det(A)|=1 \right\}  \triangleleft  GL(3,Z_{2^n})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

${\rm GL}(3,{\mathbb Z}/(2^n{\mathbb Z}))$ has a normal subgroup $N$ of order $2^{9(n-1)}$ with $G/N$ isomorphic to the simple group ${\rm GL}(3,2)$, so a longest subnormal series (i.e. a composition series) has length $9(n-1)+1$.

Comment: I understood how to construct this group, but i didn't quite understand how its order is connected with length of composition series, could you please explain?

Comment: In a finite solvable group the composition factors are all cyclic of prime order, so the length of a composition series is just the number of prime factors of its order. In particular, groups of prime power order are solvable, so the length of a composition series of a group of order $p^n$ (with $p$ prime) is $n$.